# incompatible types error in toast declaration

Tags: coordinates, toast, motionevent, incompatibletypeerror

im trying to create a toast with a message that displays the coordinates depending where the user clicks on the screen. when i declare 'mContext=this' i get an error: incompatible types required: Context.

@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
        {
          //motionevent detects motion from the user
          float x;
          x = event.getX();
          float y;
          y = event.getY();
           Context mContext;
          switch (event.getAction())
          {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

//touch_up(x, y);

mContext= this;

```
            float Cox = event.getRawX();
            float Coy = event.getRawY();
            String text = "You clicked at x = " + Cox+ "and y =" + Coy;
            //AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder();
            Toast.makeText(mContext, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //toast.show();
            invalidate();
            break;
      }
      return true;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this within an Activity or Fragment?
`this` will work in an Activity, however in a Fragment you will need to call the context of the host Activity.

Something like: 
`mContext = getActivity();
Toast.makeText(mContext, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`